# ignore script with roxygen2

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am writing a package that does some work on a server. I have a script that updates a table but my intention was not to run it manually and infrequently. It's not a function that needs to go into the namespace or anything, just a script.

The problem is that when I call `roxygen2::roxygenize()` it runs this script and takes a while to run which is very annoying while I'm trying to develop the interactive functions. I know that I can add `\donotrun{}` around the examples in my documentation but that doesn't quite make sense in this context. Is there a way that I can tell roxygen to not bother executing this?

I considered making this a function just so that executing it would just define the function body but that seems a little sideways.

Any suggestions would be great

Comment: It's not `roxygen2`'s job to determine which of the `@examples` scripts should be executed. Why does adding `\donotrun` *not* make sense here? As far as I can tell, it's precisely what that macro is intended for.

Comment: @r2evans The portion I am trying to suppress is not part of the examples, it's the entire .r file. This script is not meant to be run interactively, it just generates some data that is necessary to run the other functions.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `./R/file.R` you could save it as `./inst/file.R`. Those files are not sourced, but are instead included within the package directory when installed.

Comment: For several of my (internal) projects, I include `./inst/process.R`, which walks through use of the functions within that package (and/or dependent packages). I don't use it as a vignette, though one might infer some package semantics from that file. It is never sourced or run during package check, documentation, or loading, but the file is available to the user in all case. (Note that the file will be `./inst/file.R` in your directory, but when somebody `install.packages(...)` it, then it will be `./file.R`, not within an `inst` subdirectory.)

Comment: @r2evans That worked wonderfully. I think it would even be preferable for this file not to come with other installations as I want to control how that data set is created. What's the meaning of the `inst` dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new visitors, this is not code within roxygen documentation for a function; for that, it would be best to surround it with `\dontrun`, as in

```r
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' something_goes_here()
#' }
myfunction <- function(...) {
```

In this case, though, it's including some files in the package itself.

1. Files you place within the `./inst/` directory are installed with the packages, but they are not assumed to be R scripts (or anything, for that matter). The authoritative reference for this starts with *"Writing R Extensions"*, [Section 1.1.5 Package sub-directories](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories). This will install the file(s) on each computer that installs the package via `install.packages(...)`.
2. If you want something within the package *source* but not to be installed with the package itself, I suggest you place a file in the root of the package named `.Rbuildignore` (ref: same link, now section 1.3.2 Building package tarballs). Files that are matched by these patterns will not be included in the package tarball. Whether you put the actual file within `./inst/` or anywhere else is completely up to you: if it is in the `.Rbuildignore` file, then it will be excluded from the tarball (and therefore seen/findable by the end users).